# I am trying to implement memory allocation using worst fit algorithm. Error while displaying the output

Tags: c

CODE

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


void worst_fit(int space[],int requests[],int m,int n)
{
  int cp[m];  
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    cp[i]=space[i];
  int allocation[n];
  memset(allocation,-1,sizeof(allocation));
  int check[m];
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    memset(check,0,sizeof(check));
    int max=-1;
    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
      if(requests[i]<=space[j])
      {
        check[j]=1;
        if(max==-1)
          max=j;  
      } 
    }
    //printf("%d \n",requests[i]);
    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
      if(check[j]!=0)
      {
        if(space[j]>space[max])
          max=j;
      }  
    }
    //printf("%d \n",requests[i]);
    allocation[i]=cp[max];//copy of space should done: pending
    printf("%d %d -\n",requests[i],space[max]);
    space[max]=space[max]-requests[i];
    printf("%d %d\n",requests[i],space[max]);
  }

  printf("\nProcess No.\tProcess Size\tBlock no.\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        //printf("%d\n",requests[i]);
        printf("%d \t\t%d \t\t",i+1,requests[i]);
        if (allocation[i] != -1)
            printf("%d \n",allocation[i]);
        else
            printf("Not Allocated \n");
    }
}

int main()
{
  int i;
  int s[]={100, 500, 200, 300, 600};
  int r[]={212, 417, 112, 426};
  int m = sizeof(s) / sizeof(s[0]);
  int n = sizeof(r) / sizeof(r[0]);

  worst_fit(s,r,m,n);
}
```

The output is showing an unexpected error due to the below snippet

```
printf("%d %d -\n",requests[i],space[max]);
space[max]=space[max]-requests[i];
printf("%d %d\n",requests[i],space[max]);
```

OUTPUT for the above will be

```
212 600 -
212 388
417 500 -
417 83
112 388 -
112 276
426 426 -
0 0
```

I don't understand how 426 which is stored in requests[i] is reduced to 0.

The complete output is

```
212 600 -
212 388
417 500 -
417 83
112 388 -
112 276
426 426 -
0 0

Process No. Process Size    Block no.
1       212         600 
2       417         500 
3       112         600 
4       0       Not Allocated
```

Comment: Check the value of `max`.

Comment: The value of max doesn't affect this I guess... I have displayed the state before and after the manipulation: "space[max]=space[max]-requests[i];"

Comment: `space[max]` relies on `max != -1`, something not guaranteed by prior code.

Comment: Don't guess, check the value of max as advised by dbush.

Comment: Running your program under `gdb` and setting a hardware watchpoint with the command: `watch requests[0]@4` shows that `requests[3]` is modified by the statement: `space[max] = space[max] - requests[i];`. At that point, the value of `max` is `-1` so `space[-1]` points to `requests[3]`. You are experiencing undefined behavior. Hence, ensure that `max` is _not_ -1 [as others have mentioned].

Comment: That was really helpful!! @CraigEstey